# StreamReader not working as expected

Tags: c#, io, streamreader

I have written a simple utility that loops through all C# files in my project and updates the copyright text at the top.

For example, a file may look like this;

```
//Copyright My Company, © 2009-2010
```

The program should update the text to look like this;

```
//Copyright My Company, © 2009-2010
```

However, the code I have written results in this;

```
//Copyright My Company, ï¿½ 2009-2011
```

Here is the code I am using;

```
public bool ModifyFile(string filePath, List<string> targetText, string replacementText)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) return false;
    if (targetText == null || targetText.Count == 0) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(replacementText)) return false;

    string modifiedFileContent = string.Empty;
    bool hasContentChanged = false;

    //Read in the file content
    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        string file = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //Replace any target text with the replacement text
        foreach (string text in targetText)
            modifiedFileContent = file.Replace(text, replacementText);

        if (!file.Equals(modifiedFileContent))
            hasContentChanged = true;
    }

    //If we haven't modified the file, dont bother saving it
    if (!hasContentChanged) return false;

    //Write the modifications back to the file
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        writer.Write(modifiedFileContent);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Any help/suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, I just edited you indents to make it more clear. Why not? Do you object?

Comment: sorry I dont like it when people edit my posts.

Comment: That's a basic principle on SO, so if you are going to post here, you better get used to it ;) Read the FAQ for information regarding this if you have questions.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an encoing problem.

I think you should change this line

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
```

To a variant that saves with the correct encoding (the overload that looks like this)

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, myEncoding))
```

To get the correct encoding, where you have opened the file add this line

```
myEncoding = reader.CurrentEncoding;
```

Comment: There is no constructor accepting just `String` and `Encoding`, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, he forgot to include the "append" parameter. So what?.. I dont agree -1 with you @abatishchev . Øyvind Bråthen said what the error is.

Comment: My bad. Fixed the example now. The logic should work well, except for the mixing up of Stream/string constructors.

Comment: HABJAN: I think it's quite a harsh downvote for a "typo", but that is his choice...

Comment: As soon as you fixed your answer, I'm happy to upvote it ;) When it was wrong - I was unhappy do downvote it ;)

Comment: I really love to upvote correct answers :) Downvoting is of course an upsetting but effective way to point to a mistake. Nevermind, really.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
StreamWriter(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding)
```

i.e.

```
new StreamWriter(filePath, false, new UTF8Encoding())
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the Encoding from reader and use it in writer.

Changed code:

```
public bool ModifyFile(string filePath, List targetText, string replacementText)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) return false;
    if (targetText == null || targetText.Count == 0) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(replacementText)) return false;

    string modifiedFileContent = string.Empty;
    bool hasContentChanged = false;
    Encoding sourceEndocing = null;

    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        sourceEndocing = reader.CurrentEncoding;
        string file = reader.ReadToEnd();

        foreach (string text in targetText)
            modifiedFileContent = file.Replace(text, replacementText);

        if (!file.Equals(modifiedFileContent))
            hasContentChanged = true;
    }

    if (!hasContentChanged) return false;

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, sourceEndocing))
    {
        writer.Write(modifiedFileContent);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You have to specify the [encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx)**

[`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx) should do the trick.

Once you've sorted it [please promise me to read this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: This constructor accepts `(Stream, Encoding)` but OP uses `String`

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: OP don't use the constructor you're talking about because it accepts stream as a parameter while OP uses a file path

Comment: @abatishchev - Harsh on downvoting today?

Comment: Does more **bold text** make your answer **more clear**? Or yes, it **does**!

Comment: I believe it does - its specifies the answer succinctly in bold then goes on in more detail.  You having a bad day @abatishchev?

Comment: No, I don't have. I see no reason to bold a line in answer where just 3 lines. It's clear enough. Ok, your right to highlight anything you want :) Just edit your post to point to to another, the correct constructor and I will upvote it, until that I'm sure that your answer is incorrect and should be downvoted

Answer (score -1):

I'll bet it's related to the encoding of the file contents. Make sure you instantiate your StreamWriter with the correct encoding. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt.aspx )

Comment: Well gee thanks for the neg-vote bitch slap. Edited accordingly.